# Group by a field in my sql and concatinate another field values as one string

Tags: mysql

My table is something like that.

```
Location | Building | Department | 

L1        | B1       | D1      
L2        | B2       | D2      
L3        | B1       | D3
```

What I want to do is a query that counts locations and groups by buildings, but then display departments in that building as a string

```
Building | Count L | Departments | 

B1        | 2       | D1,D3     
B2        | 1       | D2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Group_Concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

**Definition:**

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values

The query would be like:

```
Select 
   Building, 
   count(Location) as `Count L`, 
   group_concat(Department) as Departments
From
   your_table
Group By
   Building
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select building, Count(location) as 'Count L', GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(Departments,'')) 
from yourtable
group by building
```

This will help with nulls also.

Comment: Actually use backtick `` in `mysql` to escape that name column.. Not single quote.. :)

Comment: I thought the GROUP_CONCAT does not return the null values on its own. At least this is what I get from the documentation.

"This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values
"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat